# How to create multiple synchornised text panels with text aligned based on time stamp in HTML

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to create multiple synchornised text panels with text aligned based on time stamp in HTML. I have enclosed a screenshot of the requirement

[image]

I have done some investigation and observed that simple way of implementation is to use div tags and use scrollTop methods in JQuery. However I am not sure how to align the text in the multiple panels based on time stamp;
For instance in the enclosed image time stamp "10:30 AM" in the second panel should be displayed after the text in the first panel.

Please let me know how can I implement this. Can I use any existing UI libraries?

Comment: Maybe something like getting the height of the element in source 1 and using that as the margin for the top element in source 2?

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for your quick response. By the height of the element you mean height of the text content in the Div or Panel? Also if the user resizes the window it should not effect the display, not sure how the resizing will effect if we  consider the height.